# Cache problems when generating links with the LinkManager class

Tags: link-manager

I use the following block of code to generate the links of media items in a specific language:

```
    Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions urlOptions = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
    urlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
    urlOptions.Language = Language.Parse(item.Lang);
    string lnk = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(pdfItem, urlOptions);

...
linkfield.Url = lnk;
```

The link generated looks like this:

http://cd5-int.global.com/-/media/Files/Mediaroom/700767.pdf

My problem is it keeps redirecting me to the last language version i clicked on.  It seems to be a cache problem because when i click the link opening my media, if the pdf opened in a new window is in the wrong language, i just need to refresh the page and then the pdf appears in the right language.

Did i miss some useful options in my `urlOptions` object ?

Comment: Have you tried using the `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl()` method to generate your media links instead?

Answer (score 2):

For media items you should use the `MediaManager` to generate links instead of the `LinkManager`. The `MediaManager` will return a link to the actual media item.

```
var urlOptions = new MediaUrlOptions();
urlOptions.Language = Language.Parse(item.Lang)                
var lnk = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including the `LanguageEmbedding` option in your `UrlOptions`:

```
urlOptions.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Always;
```

That should result in a URL that has the language in the querystring, like so:

http://cd5-int.global.com/-/media/Files/Mediaroom/700767.pdf?lang=en

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately the language still does not appear in the querystring. Do you know what might cause this problem ?

Comment: Do you have different settings specified for your link provider in the config? You can check by going to `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and searching for `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider`. The attribute to look for is `languageEmbedding`.